# Why is SQLite query on two indexed columns so slow?

Tags: sqlite, query-performance

I have a table with around 65 million rows that I'm trying to run a simple query on.  The table and indexes looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE E(
    x INTEGER,
    t INTEGER,
    e TEXT,
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,
    PRIMARY KEY(x,t,e,I)
);
CREATE INDEX ET ON E(t);
CREATE INDEX EE ON E(e);
```

The query I'm running looks like this:

```
SELECT MAX(t), B, C FROM E WHERE e='G' AND t <= 9878901234;
```

I need to run this queries for thousands of different values of t and was expecting each query to run in a fraction of a second.  However, the above query is taking nearly 10 seconds to run!

I tried running the query plan but only get this:

```
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE E USING INDEX EE (e=?)
```

So this should be using the index.  With a binary search I would expect worse case only 26 tests, which I would be pretty quick.

Why is my query so slow?

Comment: I was wondering if it behaves differently if you do "SELECT MAX(t), B, C FROM E WHERE t <= 9878901234 and e = 'G';" ?

Comment: @Keshav nope, it takes about the same amount of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each table in a query can use one index. Since your `WHERE` clause looks at multiple columns, you can use a multi-column index. For these, all but the last column used from the index has to test for equality; the last one used can be used for greater than/less than.

So:

```
CREATE INDEX e_idx_e_t ON E(e, t);
```

should give you a boost.

For further reading about how Sqlite uses indexes, the [Query Planner documentation](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) is a good introduction.

You're also mixing an aggregate function (`max(t)`) and columns (`B` and `C`) that aren't part of a group. In [Sqlite's case](https://sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause), this means that it will pick values for `B` and `C` from the row with the maximum `t` value; other databases usually throw an error.

Comment: That's awesome!  Query time reduced from ~10s to 6ms.  Thanks!