# SQLite, select greatest nearest value from same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a such database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE callchain(
  seq_no INT,
  entry_oid INT,
  leave_oid,
  tid INT,
  pid INT,
  depth
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX callchain_idx on callchain(seq_no);
```

And for each row in this table I want to select nearest corresponding following row where `tid`, `pid` is the same, `leave_oid` is not null and `entry_oid` is null, and `seq_no` is larger than current `seq_no` (seq_no is unique for a table), and where depth is less by 1 from current one.

I have written a query for this:

```
select *, (select min(seq_no) from callchain where seq_no > cc.seq_no and cc.pid = pid and cc.tid = tid and leave_oid not null and depth = cc.depth -1) from callchain as cc;
```

Unfortunately, this query tooks too long time (almost endless) on 1000000 records (and I need something like 100000000 records...)

Basically, this is a trace record from running program. Where `entry_oid` is not null on function entry, and `leave_oid` is not null on function exit. And I want to find function exit record for each function entry record. For example, there is a piece of the table:

```
seq_no    entry_oid  leave_oid  tid  pid  depth
--------  ---------  ---------  ---  ---  -----
2         117544                24   21   1    
3         117545                24   21   2    
4                    117556     24   21   1    
5                    117557     24   21   0    
6                    117558     24   21   -1   
7         117546                24   21   0    
8         117547                24   21   1    
9                    117559     24   21   0    
10        117548                24   21   1    
11        117549                24   21   2    
12                   117560     24   21   1    
13                   117561     24   21   0    
14                   117562     24   21   -1   
15                   117563     24   21   -2
```

For row #7 (entry point) corresponding exit point will be row #14.

I have tried to write JOIN query for the same, like the following:

```
select A.seq_no, min(B.seq_no), B.leave_oid from callchain as A inner join callchain as B on A.seq_no < B.seq_no AND A.tid=B.tid AND A.pid=B.pid AND B.leave_oid NOT NULL AND B.depth = A.depth - 1  GROUP BY A.seq_no   ORDER BY A.seq_no;
```

But I had no big succes with this query. It takes too large time too. :-(

With correlated subquery, as I understood data first is divided by `seq_no` and then by `pid/tid/depth` (or vice versa). And single index is not sufficient for both cases (index by `seq_no` or index by `pid/tid/depth`). And after data is divided previously build index becomes not valid, so SQLite engine builds temporary B-tree and all becomes too slow...

Why join query is slow I not understood, looks there is no any temporary indices build, just by algorithmic complexity is too large.

I want to ask, how can I rewrite my query and/or redesign a database to perform a query I want quickly (in a few seconds) ?

I am using SQlite engine as embedded database for C++ program. I want to avoid switching to full featured DBMS.

Comment: Looks like I have found an answer, and looks this is SQLite-specific thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781024/why-is-sqlite-query-on-two-indexed-columns-so-slow

I just created index where `seq_no` is last in the list and all works fast:
`create index callchain_idx on callchain(tid,pid,depth,seq_no);`.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a covering index**

Since your query filters and joins on `tid`, `pid`, `seq_no`, `depth` and `leave_oid`, adding a covering index on these columns will allow the query to be satisfied purely from the index without hitting the main table:

```
CREATE INDEX callchain_cover_idx ON callchain (tid, pid, seq_no, depth, leave_oid);
```

**Use a CTE to filter first**

Apply the conditions on leave_oid and depth first in a CTE to reduce the dataset before joining:

```
WITH filtered AS (
  SELECT * FROM callchain
  WHERE leave_oid IS NOT NULL AND depth >= 0
)

SELECT 
  c1.seq_no, 
  MIN(c2.seq_no) as exit_seq_no,
  c2.leave_oid
FROM callchain c1
JOIN filtered c2
ON c1.tid = c2.tid AND 
   c1.pid = c2.pid AND
   c2.depth = c1.depth - 1 AND
   c2.seq_no > c1.seq_no
GROUP BY c1.seq_no
ORDER BY c1.seq_no;
```

**Use an IN subquery instead of a join**

This may perform better by doing direct index lookups:

```
SELECT
  c1.seq_no,
  (
    SELECT MIN(c2.seq_no) 
    FROM filtered c2
    WHERE 
      c2.tid = c1.tid AND
      c2.pid = c1.pid AND  
      c2.depth = c1.depth - 1 AND
      c2.seq_no > c1.seq_no
  ) AS exit_seq_no,
  c1.leave_oid
FROM callchain c1
```